# Python to run a piece of code at a defined time every day

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

In my python program, I would like it to run a piece of code at a pre-defined time every weekday, let say 2pm Mon - Fri.

How may I do it please?

Comment: you want you python script to run 24/7 and execute specific tasks at specific times? why not have specialized scripts and use `crontab` (assuming you are on linux)  or `Taskschd.msc` on windows?

Comment: This depends on your operating system.  You'll likely want to use the `os` and `sys` packages to invoke the scheduling tool provided by your OS.

Comment: If you are running on a windows machine then see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron for an alternative for linux cronetab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python script to do something at the same time every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088037/python-script-to-do-something-at-the-same-time-every-day)

Answer (score 31):

You can use "schedule" library

to install, on terminal enter:

```
pip install schedule
```

here is an example of the code you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I am doing this job!")


schedule.every().monday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().tuesday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().thursday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().friday.at("14:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

or you can read the documents to see the other functions [Click Here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

good luck!

Comment: @Victor you are welcome, please mark it as correct answer ( because I already have projects using it LOL )

Comment: will it behave like a cron? How can I deploy this?

Comment: is possible to implemented with something more Cron style? to not leaving the while true and the script active

Comment: Is this solution, under the condition that the computer is on

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of crontab linux utility,
Crontab (CRON TABle) is a file which contains the schedule of cron entries to be run and at specified times.

for your question , goto the python file's directory and enter in terminal

```
crontab -e
```

then within crontab file you can enter like this , for eecuting at 2.30pm daily

```
30 14 * * *         python3 your_python_file.py
```